# Custom page as the index of a section, and listing content anywhere

Tags: hugo

I'm new to Hugo, so excuse if I use the wrong terms - please correct me if I do. Let me explain what I need to do.

Let's consider a travel agency's site. The agency has "offers", and they are organized into "categories" (and maybe subcategories, if the category has a `parent` property in the front matter). If I got Hugo right, "offers" and "categories" should be two sections, and I should have a folder structure like this, with each page in `content/offers` referencing a category in its front matter:

```
content
|- categories
|  |- europe.md
|  |- americas.md
|  |- asia.md
|  |- italy.md
|  |- france.md
|- offers
   |- a-week-in-paris.md
   |- new-york-and-the-east-cost.md
   |- milan-unknown-history.md
   |- indian-charm.md
```

I want to make a category's page so that it lists its subcategories and its offers: I should do this in the `layouts/categories/single.html` layout, am I right? However, how do I get the collection of its subcategories (i.e., categories that have "this category" in the `parent` property) or the collection of its offers (i.e., offers that have "this category" in the `category` property)?

I also want to have a "root" page for the offers, that only shows the list of the five top categories (i.e., categories that don't have a `parent` property). Let's say I don't want this page to be a "regular" category page, but a custom page; maybe it's not even at an URL like `/categories`, but something like `/browse-offers`. If I make a page (by creating both `content/browse-offers.md` and `layouts/_default/browse-offers.html`), how can I access the list of categories? Should I make it the "list" page of the "categories" section instead? What if the "list" page of the categories is supposed to be a filtered list of all categories instead?

I got the idea that Hugo was extremely flexible, but all the documentation and the examples I can find always talk about a plain posts/list-of-posts site structure. What if I wanted to show a gallery of "top offers" in the homepage? I can't find how to get a list of "things" unless I do it in a "list" page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can walk over the categories (in any layout) and check the 'parent' Parameter like this:

```
{{ range (where .Site.RegularPages "Section" "categories" ) }}
  {{ if .Params.parent }}
    ...
  {{ else }}
    ...
  {{ end }}
{{ end }}
```

Comment: This is not exactly what I was looking for, but it is the right pointer. `.Site.RegularPages` is the collection I was looking for, even though I need to filter it by `Section`. Thank you!